# jquery function run once inside event

Tags: jquery, events, fullpage.js

i am using fullpage.js plugin, and have one function inside the event onLeave, here is the jquery code

```
  onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
        $('#section-first').find('.a').each(function() {  // i want run once then off / remove this function
          if (index >= 2 && direction == 'up') {
            $(this).removeClass('b');
          }
    });
```

its not click function, i dont know how can i off / remove this function after it run once, still use on / off? but where i put the on? thanks so much :)

Comment: Where have you defined `onLeave`. Can you show the whole function.

Comment: sorry i dont know how to show that :( , because onLeave event come with fullpage.js plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest approach is probably to select only those elements that have both class `a` and class `b`.

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
    $('#section-first .a.b').each(function() {
        if (index >= 2 && direction == 'up') {
            $(this).removeClass('b');
        }
    });
}
```

That way, the function will still run but will do nothing unless fresh elements with `class="a b"` have been added to `#section-first`.

Not that it should matter. In normal sized DOMs, there's virtually no penalty in attempting to remove class `b` when it has already been removed. If the DOM is very large then, yes, find some way to detach the callback.

And please note that, whatever you end up doing, the function woule be better written with the jQuery inside the `if(){...}` clause :

```
onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
    if (index >= 2 && direction == 'up') {
        $('#section-first .a.b').removeClass('b');
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks so much, its work, two method also work, very good :) and i write jquery inside if(){} now, thanks for your answer :)